# Roblox | how to wait without script stopping?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a Map selection gui in Roblox with vote counter for each map but if I use wait() to call results function (I mean, function that chooses map with most votes) it also delays server to client votes display, any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very simple method is to `spawn` a new thread to do the work in.

```
print("I should appear first")

spawn(function()
    wait(3)
    print("I should appear third")
end)

print("I should appear second")
```

Comment: Thanks I were looking for answer for so much time and that simple thing worked!! Yey